# ComboBox onChange event does not fire

Tags: xpages

I cannot seem to get the onChange event to fire in the xp:comboBox. The djComboBox works fine, but I have other issues with that which are not relevant here.

There is no issue with events such as onBlur

These two snippets show the problem, I am probably missing something obvious, but any help is appreciated.

```
<xp:comboBox id="comboBox1" style="width:130.0px"
    value="#{viewScope.xpcombo}" disableClientSideValidation="true" immediate="true">
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="" id="selectItem3"></xp:selectItem>
    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Cease" itemValue="Cease"
        id="selectItem1">
    </xp:selectItem>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onChange" submit="true"
        refreshMode="full" id="eventHandler1" disableValidators="true">
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:comboBox>
                <xp:text id="computedField1">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var req = getComponent("comboBox1").getValue();
 if( req == "Cease") {return "Some cease text frome combBox1";}
}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:text>
                
                

<xe:djComboBox id="djComboBox" style="width:130.0px"
                    value="#{viewScope.djcombo}" immediate="true">

                    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="" id="selectItem5">
                    </xp:selectItem>
                    <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Cease"
                        itemValue="Cease" id="selectItem6">
                    </xp:selectItem>
                    
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onChange" submit="true" refreshMode="full" 
                        id="eventHandler2"  disableValidators="true">
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xe:djComboBox>
        
                
                <xp:text id="computedField2">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var req = getComponent("djComboBox").getValue();
if( req == "Cease") {
return "Some cease text frome djCombBox";}
}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:text>
```

Comment: Try checking the data source instead. So try for example: viewScope.xpcombo == "Cease"

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to make it a simple example for illustration. The combobox is bound to a back end document, so that won't work unless I save it on each change, which seems wrong? Strangely it works as intended if it is contained within a dialogbox.

Comment: My point is that you should check the data source in your computed field instead of using getComponent

Comment: Thanks Per Henrik, but that doesn't make any difference. Again it works with the djcombobox but not the xpcombobox.
There is nothing firing in the browser monitor or console.

Comment: Have you tried to break it out into a new xpage?

Comment: Per Henrik - you are correct, I had a typo due to switching between 
xp event="onchange"   v   xe event="onChange" Grrrr

Sorry to have wasted your time, your solution did work.

Comment: So checking the data source instead of using getComponent works? If so, then I will add this as an answer that you can accept

Comment: Yes please, if you add I will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the data source instead of the component (using getComponent). So try for example: `viewScope.xpcombo == "Cease"`